# Grab HTML code from web

Tags: c#, html, string

I'm working on a project for fun but i want to grab just the html code from a website which I will later have to extract just the links.

I've been googling for a few minutes and I haven't found anything that does what I want specifically (just the text).

Comment: I... can't.... resist... "specifically"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://born2code.net");
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Comment: I heard that will only work if the page i use as my target validates as html. is that true?

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is rather forgiving of malformed HTML - if it displays in a browser, the library can likely parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at a standard tool like [Httrack](http://www.httrack.com/), or if you want to actually want the html if you're programming for fun look at [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful to me a while ago -- [Parsing HTML in C#](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/2230091/Parsing-HTML-in-Microsoft-C.htm)